# Enabling flash based on active device in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: swift2, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a view which is providing the controls via `UIImagePickerController.cameraOverlayView` . For these controls, I only want to enable them based on the current capability of the active capture device. For example, only enable the 'torch' if the device has that capability.

Looking at `UIImagePickerController` it has a `cameraDevice` property, but that is only an enumeration, so that doesn't help.

My current code (based in code elsewhere on stack overflow):

```
func toggleTorch(on: Bool) -> Bool {
    var success = false
    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if device.hasTorch {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()

            if on == true {
                device.torchMode = .On
            } else {
                device.torchMode = .Off
            }

            device.unlockForConfiguration()
            success = true
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Torch could not be used")
        }
    } else {
        debugPrint("Torch is not available")
    }
    return success
}
```

I would like to be able to make the device correspond to the active device the current UIImagePickerController? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I missed the fact UIImagePickerController already provides the functionality I need.

To see if current device has a flash:

```
UIImagePickerController.isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice(cameraController?.cameraDevice)
```

And to set the mode (auto/on/off):

```
cameraController?.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode.Auto
```